# How to put background colour for action bar in android

Tags: android

How can i change the background of the action bar instead of that default black one. I want something like how other social networking android applications are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("yourColor")));
```

Comment: Are you using an `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: no bro , I am using main activity and calling the above code in oncreate

Comment: But what is `MainActivity` extending? `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`? If you are using `Activity` you will get a null pointer.

Comment: Yes, exactly that's the case.. can you tell me more on why I got a nullpointerexception ? any pointers ?

Comment: Search on how to use `ActionBar` and `ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Styling the Action bar topic here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom style

```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
          <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:background">#FF9D21</item>
    </style>
```

Snap. (Ignore the other changes made to ActionBar)

[image]

For more info

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes in your style.xml

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">#ffooff</item>
</style>
```