# Android: Error trying to change the background of an actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, action

I am trying to do change the background color of the action bar.
I am following tutorial from this site:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Chapter on Styling the action bar

I receive an error which I can't work out the origin of.
The error is on this line of code

```
Android Manifest.xml
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/CustomActionBarTheme').
Could anybody explain why this line throws an error?

Code:
     Android Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp2.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    </application>

   </manifest>
```

Code: themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

code: styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go    

 here. -->
</style>

 </resources>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516245/how-to-put-background-colour-for-action-bar-in-android/20516289#20516289. what is the error?. Move it to `styles.xml`

Comment: Hi

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/CustomActionBarTheme').

at 
Android Manifest.xml
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"

Comment: Hi
When I do that:
I get a new error

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.

please advise

Comment: on

     <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"

Comment: no need for the change its the same. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

Comment: use `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and no need for change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370816/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-holo-light-darkacti